# In RoR, do I have to specify every controller method as a route by hand?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What I'm wondering, in this case where I want to create a few web service type controllers, is if there is a way to "export" what method is allowed to be called from the controller. I'm still very new to RoR, and its routes feature, but in the end, is it expected that a fully functional RoR application just has hundreds of routes? Not every controller method I'm creating falls into a "resource" category.

Comment: It is expected you will write routes for every URL you want to use, yes. The vast majority of your routes should fall under resources.

Comment: If that is what is expected of the RoR developer, then that is what I'll do. :D Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails routes come in several varieties – RESTful routes are merely the ones that happen to provide native support for Rails resources. Remember that event resource routes can be modified to have member and collection routes:

```
# routes.rb
resources :products do
  member do
    get 'short' #=> products/:product_id/short/:id
    post 'toggle' #=> products/:product_id/toggle/:id
  end

  collection do
    get 'sold' #=> products/sold
  end
end
```

You can also nest resource routes within other resource routes:

```
# routes.rb
resources :products do
  resources :comments #=> RESTful routes patterned as products/:product_id/comments/:id/:action
  resources :sales do
    get 'recent', :on => :collection
  end
end
```

Another handy feature is named routing. The following route is **not** resourceful:

```
# routes.rb
match 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', :as => :purchase # Creates route path akin to purchase_path(:id)
```

Namespaced routes can be very helpful for organization and readability:

```
# routes.rb
namespace :admin do
  resources :products #=> RESTful routes patterned as admin/products/:product_id/:action
end
```

So, basically, there's a route for everything you want to do, whether it's RESTful/resourceful or not. But **yes, you need to write a route for every action** you want exposed to your app.

Comment: Even though both answers gave me the correct information, this one gave me the namespace hint. I like that. :)

Answer (score 2):

Using the `routes.rb` file, you can create routes or pattern matching for routes, as well as parameterized routes, and nested routes. You should read more about this [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

You can also give routes their own method name such as `my_new_route_path`. If you **really** wanted to, you could just hardcode routes into your HTML. Please don't do this.

Every controller action needs routes that map to it.

Comment: sevenseacat helped answer this as well. There will be cases where I want the route to be "hardcoded" (external applications/clients). I understand now that just specifying routes is the RoR mo. Thanks!